# Required new 'X' desktop for VNC?

Tags: networking, xorg, remote, vnc

I'm on Raspberry pi 2, running Raspian, and using Ubuntu 14.04. I am using the tightvncserver. I don't think I should have to start a new 'X' desktop each time I want to VNC into the pi, but whenever I tried to vnc into the previously established :0 or :1 it told me that it was "closed" and refused to connect. This is after running:

```
 vncserver :0 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24
```

I got it running by typing the same thing with a :2 and then vnc-ing in, but I think there's another way.

Comment: When you connect on :2 are the previously started vncserver processes still running?

Comment: I put into the command line "vncserver -kill :0" which it told me couldn't be done.  I wasn't sure if this meant the other processes were still running or I just have no idea what I'm doing...probably both

Comment: Well, if the server is no longer running it explains why you can't re-connect to it :) You need to explain where that 'kill' fits into the picture. Also might help if you describe how you end your VNC session.

Comment: I end the VNC session by closing the VNc window as expalined here:          [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/linux.md).  The funny part is that when I go into recent connections to reconnect and click on any of the previous options it tells me it's closed. If I enter in the command I have in the original question it says it can't do that because there is some kind of tmp file, sort of like what ubuntu 12 used to do if you closed the lid without suspending, but I have no idea how to get rid of these files.

Comment: Right now I've got it sort of working via going through and sudo rm-ing all the files it outlines as causing issues, but this seems a little janky and unreliable as well as tedious. Is there something else I should be doing, or is this relly the best way to do this.

Comment: If you don't specifically kill the servers they may be dying for some reason, leaving behind their lockfiles. You may find details in the logfiles located in your ~/.vnc dir.

Comment: Another possibility is that the lower display numbers are in use by the regular Xorg server (not vncserver), running as root - that would prevent you from running your own server under 0: for example. Sounds plausible since you mention sudo for removing the lockfiles. If so - either run your vncserver as :2 or higher (whichever you can start yourself) or access your pi's Xorg server using vnc instead (needs configuration, tho).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to operate it as if both of those are true and clean up the server when I'm done using it each time. I think that's really the only option.